# Dynamic configuration file in Nodejs and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am working with NodeJs with expressjs and I would like to use a middleware that will read a variable from dynamic configuration file before each request (some js file that holds an object that I can change manually while the server is running).
I would like to store a flag that will close down all requests (i.e send response without proceeding to next routes) until I change the variable value to true and then the middleware will call next() so all routes will work.
I prefer to avoid shutting down the server for that, and I also don't want to store this variable in a database...

Is there something similar to what I need?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "close down all requests"?

Comment: i will put this function(see below) as a middleware before all the get\post\put routes in my server.
function(req,res,next){
if (confFile.confs.registrationStatus==="open"){
next();
}else{
res.send("registration closed");
}
}

i also edited the question for clearity

Comment: Take a look at other's responses below(but never read file synchronously though when you're processing the request!). I don't have time to provide you with exact implementation right now, but you should consider using `fs.watch` function to register callback for file changes and read file only when it's necessary.

Comment: it feels from the comments below that what i'm trying to achieve is a bad practice. i need something which is very simple, to control using middleware function a handling request by a dynamic property (i.e registration closed\registration open). what is the best option in your opinion? define a configuration table in a database, and read the property each time in the database or shutdown the server, change the code of the middleware and start it again?
reading a file every time using FS seems like a very bad option.

Answer (score 1):

You will read config.json file each time, if you just put it inside function. If you will use require('config.json), then you will read this file only once on start.

```
var fs = require("fs");

function (req,res,next) { 

  var config = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
  config = JSON.parse(config.toString());

  if (config.registrationStatus === "open") { 
    next(); 
  } else { 
    res.send("registration closed");
  } 
}
```

Comment: does using Sync Fs is the best option? seems though to read this file on each request from client.

Comment: @user3286882 of course it is not option at all. I thought you need it just for testing or some kind of local project. Use DB instead or at least readFile (this will be async).

Answer (score -2):

Check supervisor: https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor

It will watch for file changes and crashes and will restart your application each time.

You will get much better performance.

Comment: it feels to me a very bad practice to restart the server for this kind of thing.
i might consider working with a different way than a configuration file (maybe database) ?
what do you thing would be the best option for me ?

Comment: @user3286882 it is not a good practice for your goal, because your full approach is wrong. But it definitely the best practice for applications in production environment at all.
You want to use either PM2 or supervisor to run your app. They will restart node server on each unhandled error, so you will not leak resources as crazy and your app will be always running.

Comment: can you please tell me what is wrong with my approach ?
how can i enable\disable a service of a web server dynamically?